# Signal can't wake up sleeping process

Tags: c, linux, process, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on a project which requires to take care of process scheduling. I tried to stop certain process by sending SIGINT signal(ctrl+c), but i found out sleeping process doesn't wake up.
I solved this weird issue but couldn't find out why SIGINT signal couldn't wake up sleeping process.

Here's my original code (where process is stuck) :

```
            set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
            while (!item->assigned) {
                schedule_timeout(2*HZ);
               set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
            }
            set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
```

So inside of the while loop, when `!item->assigned` is still 1, SIGINT signal doesn't do anything even though process' state is set to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`.

As far as I know, process takes care of signal in these ways:

> 1. execute the signal default action
> 2. block the signal setting a signal mask (this is done using the system call sigmask)
> 3. assign a custom handler to the signal, executing a custom action (using the system call signal)

So in this case I assumed It would execute the default action..

I added `signal_pending(current)` to check if there is any pending signal, and if it is, then break out of the loop so that the process can handle the pending signal.

```
            set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
            while (!item->assigned) {
                schedule_timeout(2*HZ);
                if (signal_pending(current))
                {

                    break;
                }
                set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
            }
            set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
```

But still no idea why It didn't catch the SIGINT signal.

Comment: Is it `set_current_state` or `__set_current_state`? Pick one.

Comment: Are you sure the task doesn't have the signal masked?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Oh, It's `set_current_state`. Sorry for the confusion. I edited the question! And yes, I didn't block any signal. For more information, I tested this code on Rasberry pi3, (has 4 cores) with tizen kernel(https://wiki.tizen.org/Linux). Not sure this information would be of help.

Comment: It probably did handle it.  It woke up finished the loop, condition still existed so it when back to sleep.  You could test that by putting in a print/logging message in the loop and see if it outputs when you send SIGINT.

Comment: @estabroo Hi, I tried to test it more with `printf` function, but i get this error consistently even though added `sched.h` in /usr/include directory. `undefined reference to set_current_state` why this error happens? `set_current_state` is defined in `sched.h`, so I can't figure out why...

Comment: @ProbieH undefined reference happens when it can't find it at the linking stage, you need to add the library that those functions are in, add -l<name of library> to the compilation.  For example `gcc -o threaded_blah threaded_blah.c -lpthread`. But you've made me curious how you compiled it originally if now you are getting undef'd refs.  Plus I think set_current_state is a kernel function not a userspace one, so which side of the fence are you playing in?

Comment: @estabroo Oh I wrote the codes on the post in Kernel space(on Tizen kernel), and then I just wanted to test the copy of the above code in a new file to check It handles pending signal appropriately inside of the while loop. Process knows there is a pending signal, but It is not handled correctly. Still no idea.. Maybe I should study thoroughly how schedule() functions work.

Comment: May be this will give you a better understanding, kernel signals aren't handled like userspace signals. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355280/how-signals-are-handled-in-kernel